# DocumentException: Font '' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized.starck

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I try generate a report with jasper reports, but when i run the code, I have the following error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: Font '' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized.
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getFont(JRPdfExporter.java:2062)

The part of my code that I run is

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(relatorio, baos);

    InputStream documentInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    download = new InputStreamDownload(documentInput, "application/pdf",
            arquivo, true, baos.toByteArray().length);

    return download;
```

The stranger is that other reports working Usually with this code

Comment: *Font '' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized* looks like a font with an empty name.

Comment: all my springs are in the property name as <INHERITED>

Comment: You may want to share your report definition for inspection.

Comment: How come my definition report?

Comment: Your report definition is the jrxml file defining the report generation.